# Cylinder Set and It's Importance

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to learn the Cylinder set. From Wikipedia, I have learned its definition. But still, confused about how a set could create a Cylinder Shape? Why this set is called a Cylinder set. Most of the Books have given the definition. But they didn't mention why it has this kind of name and why we study this? Maybe this is trivial to everyone but I am new here and not understanding. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: The product topology has a canonical basis. Each basis element is called a cylinder set. Semantics.

Comment: Thank you @AlvinLepik.

Comment: Probably in contrast to the box topology (Which is the same as the product on finite cross products, but different when things get infinite)